# How do properly use an array label names for a custom axis on D3?

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js, axis, label

I'm trying to make custom labels for my x-axis on D3. My current solution throws in the array elements randomly, but I'd like it to be in a specific order. How can this be done properly in with tickformat? My current code is pasted below:

```
        var formatAxis = function(d) {
           return arr[d % arr.length];      
        }

        xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(xScale)
            .orient("bottom")
            .tickValues(createTickValuesArray(arr.length))
            .tickFormat(formatAxis);
```

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is something you can't do with `.tickFormat()`, the order depends on the scale you're using. I'm guessing you're using an ordinal scale?

Comment: No, I'm using a linear scale. Why does the scale decide which order the ticks are written in? I'd assume it'd just take the content of the array one by one?

Comment: Yes, but the scale determines where they go -- i.e. if your first element is 6 and the second 5, 5 will still appear before 6 on the axis. Not sure what you mean by specific order now. Could you give an example please?

Comment: Yes, of course. Other than data for the datapoints I aquire and array from the database. This array has the label name for each data point. When I print this array out using `console.log`, this is the output: ["t(15;17)", "inv(16)/t(16;16)", "t(8;21)", "t(11q23)/MLL", "complex ab. karyotype", "HSC", "MPP", "CMP", "GMP", "MEP", "early_PM", "late_PM", "MY", "MM", "BC", "PMN", "Mono"].

This array is the same I use in my `formatAxis` function. I need these labels to appear on the axis from left to right in the same order as they have in the array as it is very important for graph.

Comment: What does your `formatAxis()` function look like?

Comment: var formatAxis = function(d) {
           return arr[d % arr.length];      
        }

Comment: It is written in my question in this thread  as well

Comment: Well then you probably want `function(d, i) { return arr[i]; }` instead.

Comment: Great, I'll post that as an answer for reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the tick labels to be returned in the same order as in the array, you can use the index explicitly:

```
var formatAxis = function(d, i) {
       return arr[i];      
    }
```